# Drupal Installation issue

Tags: drupal

When I install drupal it doesn't proceed from the database and domain entry form. It does not diplays any error on entering valid database name and domain name etc. But the wizard does not proceed. I think it is mysqli database issue. All mysqli related extensions are installed and loaded on my server.

Comment: Which version of Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you loaded pdo extensions also? I guess you are on local system, it worked fine with me. I am using XAMP latest version. If you are using wampp or appserv e.t.c. like PHP setups then leave them and just shift towards xampp or if you are advanced developer then do your own installation.

Not only in drupal but also softwares like vanilla, yii framework you can face such problems while on server these sort of problem exist rarely. These problems normally happens due to pdo or such other extensions e.t.c. So why not to use XAMPP that has already these common things configured? These sort of problems are more often on local systems. On webhosting these things are mostly ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6, this is error is most likely because you renamed default.settings.php instead of *copying* it. Drupal still needs the original default.settings.php

So, try renaming it back to default.settings.php and then create a copy of it which you name settings.php

Answer (score 0):

Following is demonstration to install drupal and select version and setting virtual host

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meA4VB1Cvhs

hope it helps.